# Type Safety warning with JSON Iterator

Tags: java, android, json

My problem comes from getting an Iterator from a JSONObject.

Code generating error in its simplest form:

```
String json = client.retrieveList();
JSONObject jsonList = new JSONObject(json);
Iterator<String> i = jsonList.keys();

while(i.hasNext())
{
    String next = i.next();
    JSONArray jsonArray = jsonList.getJSONArray(next);
    // Do stuff with jsonArray, example: jsonArray.getString(0), jsonArray.getString(1);
}
```

The exact warning is:
Type safety: The expression of type Iterator needs unchecked conversion to conform to Iterator

So the question is how can I eradicate this warning?

Many thanks!

Answer (score 104, accepted):

i realize this is an old thread, but for future searchers...

you can also infer a generic and cast the returns of the iterator methods...

```
Iterator<?> i = jsonList.keys();

while(i.hasNext())
{
    String next = (String) i.next();
    ...
```

Comment: Yes, this should be the verified answer.  Eliminates the warning without having to suppress it.

Comment: This may supress the warning, however (String) i.next()  can potentially throw a runtime exception.

Answer (score 3):

When you mix your code with old legacy API-s you can get this kind of warnings. If you *really* want to "eradicate" the warning you can use the SuppressWarnings annotation. It is a good practice to leave a comment next to suppressed warning. In your case this may look like:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked") //Using legacy API
Iterator<String> i = jsonList.keys();
```

Cheers!

Comment: I was hoping that there might be a better way than to suppress it. I think that may be the course I take though.

Comment: @SuppressWarnings("unchecked") is a very dangerous habit. Suppose "jsonList" could be null -- well, now you've hidden the warning. I consider it a serious warning sign if any devs on my team use this to hide warnings. It is "good practice" to never put tape over the engine warning light, regardless of what comment you may write on said tape.

Amendment: Come to think of it, you are at least specifying the type of warning to suppress, so the null case isn't applicable. Fair enough. But it's still a dangerous habit, and the other answer does provide a more elegant solution.

Comment: Suppressing warnings is generally a bad idea, but it's fine in this case. According to the documentation, "Names are unique, non-null strings." I suppose if you want to be extra cautious, you could take the generic and inspect it yourself, but I suspect trusting the docs is okay in this case.