# Unchecked conversion

Tags: java, android, json, iterator

I don't want to supress warnings. Is there another way to handle this warning?

"The expression of type Iterator needs unchecked conversion to conform to Iterator"

```
Iterator<String> it = schemaJSON.getJSONObject("body").keys();
```

Answer (score 26, accepted):

You can find your answere here: [Type Safety warning with JSON Iterator](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4296496/type-safety-warning-with-json-iterator)

```
Iterator<?> it = schemaJSON.getJSONObject("body").keys();

while(it.hasNext())
{
     String next = (String) it.next();
     ...
```

Answer (score 6):

If you just want to remove the warning,

> "The expression of type Iterator needs unchecked conversion to conform to Iterator"

then do this,

```
Iterator<String> it =  (Iterator<String>)schemaJSON.getJSONObject("body").keys();
```

but this result in new warning but your old warning is removed.

> `Type safety: Unchecked cast from Iterator to Iterator<String>`

For removing all your warnings,

```
Iterator<?> it = schemaJSON.getJSONObject("body").keys();    
while(it.hasNext())
{
    String nextElement = (String) it.next();
```

Comment: @Nfear please accept the answer as proposed by Ben in http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20378562/unchecked-conversion/20378705#20378705 he was first to point to solution....

Answer (score 0):

I think `keys()` returns an `Iterator` instance, not an `Iterator<String>`, so you either leave the `String` away or just live with the warning ;-)

Answer (score 0):

You can't avoid this warning, because the android `JSONObject#keys()` returns a 'raw' `Iterator`. But you can suppress the warnings using the `@SuppressWarnings` annotation:

```
@SuppressWarnings("unchecked")
Iterator<String> it = schemaJSON.getJSONObject("body").keys();
```

Comment: The best answer on all dups. I came here to find out WHY there is a warning, not just how to suppress it.